# Spring Batch:How to monitor currently running jobs & show progress on jsp page

Tags: java, spring-mvc, batch-processing, spring-batch

I want to know how to monitor status of my currently running batch jobs.My jobs are basically processing folder with some default steps so I want to show progress to the user step by step .I am using [Tasklets](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/Tasklet.html) and **DB Job Repository**.Explaining with some example code for achieving this will be more helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [Spring Cloud Data Flow](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-dataflow).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to develop your own monitor app/webpage, you may want to look into the `JobExplorer` or `JobOperator` interface.  It provides you with methods to get the JobExecutions, and in JobExecutions, you can get StepExecutions.  All these give you the status of the job and individual steps inside.

---

Edit to reply for the comment:

For the quoted progress information, it is not something stored in Spring Batch.  However, the two interface DO help you on that.  First Store the progress information in the step execution context.  Then make sure your tasklet is not implemented as a synchronous task.  You have to return CONTINUABLE (forgive me if I mixed up the term, it have been some time I previous used Spring Batch), so that your tasklet will be invoked by Spring batch consecutively.  (This can be done in many way, either you break your work into piece and for each invocation of tasklet execute(), you work on only one piece of them and return FINISHED only when all pieces is completed, or you may spawn another thread to do the work, and your tasklet simply monitor the progress, etc).

By doing so, you will have step execution context continuously updated with your progress information, so you can use JobExplorer and JobOperator to get the Job Execution -> Step Execution -> Step's Execution Context for your progress reporting purpose.

Comment: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?114894-How-to-monitor-the-progress-of-a-Tasklet-to-send-to-the-GUI&s=e077b42fd45ae3a3177a01c90339893c JobExplorer and JobOperator interface won't give me step details as described in above link.BTW thanks for replying.

Comment: I am gonna give it a try..Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You should have a look at spring batch admin application.

[Spring Batch Admin](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch-admin/getting-started.html)

To quote directly: It's a regular war file. Once it's deployed, you can browse with a web browser (e.g. localhost:8080/spring-batch-admin-sample) and check out the features for launching jobs and inspecting job executions.

Surely, through some modifications, you can achieve your own requirement.

Comment: Achieved somewhat with the help of this thread http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?114894-How-to-monitor-the-progress-of-a-Tasklet-to-send-to-the-GUI&s=e077b42fd45ae3a3177a01c90339893c .I can't use spring-batch-admin because customizing its view is not a trivial task.BTW thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Batch ver 4.2 comes with batch monitoring and metrics capturing based on Micrometer .You can try to leverage the same.
Following table list some of the metrics
[image: Spring batch metrics]

Spring Batch also enables you to create your own metrics .You can check more details here https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.2.x/reference/html/monitoring-and-metrics.html#custom-metrics