# Grails status Update for long running task

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

I have a long running task (>1.5 minutes) and I want to be able to provide the user status of completion with ajax. 
Here's what I'm currently doing: 
I am using ajax to process the upload (with an ajax upload plugin) and I display a busy label while the task is running. **I want to be able to display percentage completed (Not percentage of upload - I already provide updates for that.) i.e After my excel file is done uploading and I start processing the rows, I want to be able to provide status updates to the user.**

Here's where my research/ personal knowledge has led me:
1. Use threads
2. Use JMS or some kind of messaging
3. Use grails events. (Not sure how this will work)

Anybody know what will be the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I've done this in the past I've used the following approach:

1. [Dispatch the long running process in another thread](http://tux2323.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/grails-and-spring-async-annotation.html). The long running process updates progress in some session scoped component (or in the db)
2. Return the user's browser to the page and start some [javascript that regularly polls](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) a server-side controller to get the current progress

The [jQuery UI progress bar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar) is pretty easy to use if you want to display % complete.

Comment: Do you know if Async annotation is available in tomcat7?

Comment: Yep - the @Async annotation is provided by Spring, so Tomcat version doesn't really come into it.

Comment: Ok. thanks. I'll quickly try this out then accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Spring Batch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/) for our long running tasks (= batch jobs) within our Grails application. It's a framework part of the Spring product family that is targeted at building batch jobs.

The guys at SpringSource/GoPivotal have really put a lot of thought in the overall architecture and the provided patterns. If you have more than one batch job in your application, I'd consider having a look at it.

For your specific progress requirement, Spring Batch provides components like `JobOperator` or `JobExplorer` at runtime that can be used to find out about the current batch job state. There is a separate [SO question about monitoring progress in Spring Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450952/spring-batchhow-to-monitor-currently-running-jobs-show-progress-on-jsp-page) if you like that as a starting point.