# Searching for actually running spring batch jobs

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I'm trying to find the way how to determine whether `JobExecution` obtained from `JobExplorer` is actually running. 
The problem is that explorer checks for job execution by running jdbc query. But is some cases (e.g. container with Spring Batch job was killed/restarted) jobs remain persisted in DB in running state, though they are orphaned and there is no processing actually running in runtime.

And simple method like

```java
private boolean isJobRunning(String jobName) {
    var activeExecutions = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(jobName);
    return activeExecutions
        .stream()
        .anyMatch(jobExecution -> jobExecution.getStatus().isRunning());
}
```

doesn't work as expected.

Is there any way to find **actually** active jobs? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is the right approach. How are you getting the jobExplorer object???

Comment: This approach does not work in case Spring-Batch application was stopped with uncompleted jobs running left. Those jobs have non-terminal state in Spring Batch schema and are being recognized as still active by the code above. So, my temporary solution implies keeping track of the status in runtime, changing it on job events. That solution is pretty controversial at least because it's hardly scalable.

Comment: yes, if the job is killed abruptly, it stays in the `RUNNING` status in the database. By just looking at the database (namely the status column), there is no way to distinguish between a job that is actually running and a job that was killed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Batch:How to monitor currently running jobs & show progress on jsp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450952/spring-batchhow-to-monitor-currently-running-jobs-show-progress-on-jsp-page)